# Installing Smart Switches with Continuous Line Wire

Tags: electrical

I had planned to swap out two standard switches in a double-gang box with smart switches but discovered that the line wire appears to be one continuous wire that is stripped in two sections, where it wraps around one screw terminal on each switch and then exits out of the box via a different point.

I’ve installed smart switches (which have connection wires not terminals) in other locations; however, they were single-gang boxes with ends of wires. Accordingly, I’m curious if someone could tell me the best way to proceed.

[image: Switch Wiring]

Comment: +1 for posting a picture, without us begging for it

Answer (score 3):

Cut that wire, add a pigtail or two if needed, connect all with your choice of legal-in-your-area wire connector (Wirenut/Marrette, Wago leverlock, etc...)

So long as all parts of things connected to the wire are connected, it does not actually matter HOW they are connected (*i.e.* all into a "star" and one uncut wire continuing are electrically equivalent.)

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Cut the wire in the middle of the stripped loop, straighten out the ends and strip them further. Now you have two wires like you’re use to. Wire nut them together with the pigtail to the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a strong feeling that was the path forward but wasn’t confident enough to cut.